# ISO C++17 does not allow 'register' storage class specifier

Tags: c++

Начал изучать register и сразу же столкнулся с ошибкой ISO C++17 does not allow 'register' storage class specifier. Работаю на macbook air M2(xcode). Пример кода был взят из книги "C++ классическое издание, Герберт Шилдт". В чём может быть проблема, может кто знает ? Вывод с консоли, если что, из другой программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testmainf.hpp"
using  namespace std;
int int_pwr(register int m, register int e){ //ISO C++17 does not allow 'register' storage class specifier
    register int temp; //ISO C++17 does not allow 'register' storage class specifier
    temp = 1;
    for (;e;e--) temp = temp * m;
    return temp;
}
int main() {
    int_pwr(2, 10);
}
```

Comment: Начиная с C++17 больше нет никакого `register` (осталось только зарезервированное неиспользуемое ключевое слово). Можете не тратить  время на его изучение.

Comment: @wololo Спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключевое слово `register` убрали из стандарта.

Варианты:

- Не писать его в коде (наиболее логичный вариант).
- Чтобы слово в коде игнорировалось написать что-то типа

  ```
  #define register
  ```
- Порыть в сторону `__attribute__` для форсирования помещения переменной в регистр - я не смог сейчас нагуглить, но вроде бы раньше что-то такое встречал (впрочем, подозреваю, что там надо явно указывать, какой регистр ты хочешь отдать переменной).